# Battlestar Galactica episode with a western gunfight

Tags: episode-identification, battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

Very faint memories of this, probably from the original Battlestar TV series. I've tried searching for Wild West shootout and variations but no joy.

There was like a cowboy saloon and a fighter pilot went outside and had a 'draw and shoot' with a Cylon on the street, there was something about his gun (can't remember exactly what) and anyway he won.

I'm trying to track down the episode name/number.

Comment: It sounds almost like a Red Dwarf episode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Series 1 Episode 4 ["The Lost Warrior"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519755/) contains a Cylon gunslinger. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Battlestar_Galactica_(1978_TV_series)_and_Galactica_1980_episodes#Series_1_(1978-79)) entry refers to this episode as:

> Marooned on a frontier planet, Apollo befriends a young widow and her son, rallying a town against "Red Eye"— a likewise marooned, yet memory-damaged, Cylon centurion gunslinger. **The storyline is very much reminiscent of the classic western *Shane*.**

Comment: That's it! As soon as I saw "Red Eye" I remembered it. And it was indeed reminiscent of Shane.